# How to test nuxt with jest?

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js

I'm just learning Nuxt with jest.
My test.vue. just copied from https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1 class="page-title">Mountains</h1>
    <p v-if="$fetchState.pending">Fetching mountains...</p>
    <p v-else-if="$fetchState.error">An error occurred :(</p>
    <div v-else>
      <h1>Nuxt Mountains</h1>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="mountain of mountains">{{ mountain.title }}</li>
      </ul>
      <button @click="$fetch">Refresh</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      mountains: [],
    }
  },
  async fetch () {
    this.products = await fetch(
       'https://api.nuxtjs.dev/mountains'
    ).then(res => res.json())
  }
}
</script>
```

My test.spec.js

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Test from '@/components/test.vue'

describe('Test', () => {
  test('is a Vue instance', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Test)
    const title = wrapper.find('.page-title')
    expect(title.text()).toBe("Mountains")
  })
})
```

While I run the npm run test I got this error. How can I fix this issue?

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'pending' of undefined"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there is no library to extend the nuxt component structure within vue-test-utils.

That being said you are able to to do some yourself quite easily using the mocks api.

```
mounted(Component, { mocks: { $fetchState: { pending: true, error: true, timestamp: Date.now() } } })
```

The really tricky part is that fetch is not found within the component. you can find it in options, `wrapper.vm.$options.fetch()` but no real way to test as of yet...

Comment: As we are getting the reference from `$options` I had to adjust `this` to the right context, in my case what worked was `await wrapper.vm.$options.fetch.apply(wrapper.vm, [])`